# How to call script data inside html and php tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter-3 to develop web application i have one form which contains two dropdowns it's dependent each other.for example if i select any one in the first dropdown according to that the second dropdown data has to be rendered for that i wrote **onchange** function it's taking the **value** ,what i want is the **myFunction**() returning some data i want to print that data inside the html and php tag can you please help me to acheive this thing..?

Comment: yes you can print js inside html but inside php tag not sure that you mean

Comment: yeah i mean inside html only sorry for confusion made by me

Answer (score 0):

This is example of how you can insert result from js function back to html

```js
function myFunction() {
        const e = document.getElementById("jobSel");
         job = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

          const node = document.createElement("p");
          node.innerText = job;
         document.getElementById("test").appendChild(node);
    };
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName1">Fuel Type</label>
    <select name="f_type" id="jobSel" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="">No Selected</option>
    <option value="1">Petrol</option>
    <option value="2">Diesel</option>
    <option value="3">Kerosine</option>
    <option value="4">Others</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: can i bind this value inside the value or input field

Comment: @NikhilSundarasetty yes if you want to change value of input field simple change to document.getElementById("what ever is id of input field").value = job

Comment: <?php foreach ($station_data as $row) { if ($row->fuel_type == '<script>document.write(job)</script>' ) { ?> i want to bind the value inside this condition

Comment: you cant do it because php is server side language and will be executed once on page request if you like to change Pump Name base on Fuel Type you can do it with JS after php foreach price all posible options but if you like to change Pump Name base on some other value from another page you should save this in php session/cookie... if you explain me what you trying to do i may help you

Comment: "<SCRIPT TYPE='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('test')</SCRIPT>" i tried this one but it's not binding

Comment: i have one form page ,inside that i have two dropdowns ,if i select the first dropdown based on the value i want to bind the data from the controller

Comment: ` if ($row->fuel_type == '1' )` in this line i want to check the if condition  which ever returns the value from the js

Comment: you cant do it php will execute on server side and js  will be execute on client side here is example of how should be done chek it   https://jsfiddle.net/g609bzte/